# How to close an activity when moving to another Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm building a simple app that creates a message in the notification bar by pressing a button and by pressing the message I'm running a new `Activity`.
When I close the `Activity` by pressing back and then run it again, the button press does nothing.
I also created a singleton `NotificationManager` to remove the message icon from the notification bar automatically in the onCreate method from the second activity.
It seems that my singleton class remains and no new `Object` can be created. I need to force the activity to close and I believe only then will my singleton class be released.
I tried setting `android:noHistory="true"` on both activitied in the `manifest.xml` and also created this on the `MainActivity`:

```
public void onContextMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
        super.onContextMenuClosed(menu);
        this.finish();
    }
```

And tried this on the `MessageViewer` activity:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }
```

This is my code:

```
public class NotifyManager {
    private static NotificationManager notificationManager=null;

    public static NotificationManager getInstance() {
        if(notificationManager==null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("NotificationManager has not been set yet.");
        }
        else {
            return notificationManager;
        }
    }

    public static void setNotificationManager(NotificationManager nm) throws NotificationManagerException {
        if(notificationManager==null) {
            notificationManager = nm;
        }
        else {
            throw new NotificationManagerException("NotificationManager has already been set.");
        }
    }
}



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    NotifyManager.setNotificationManager(nm);
                    Notification notify = new Notification(
                            R.drawable.icon,
                            "New message", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    Context context = MainActivity.this;
                    CharSequence title = "You have a new message";
                    CharSequence details = "";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageViewer.class);
                    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, details, pending);
                    nm.notify(0, notify);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

By the way, int my second activity, all I do is closing the current notification:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_viewer);

        NotifyManager.getInstance().cancel(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to create different notification with different ids.
In `nm.notify(0, notify);` you cant give every notification the same id.
so just try to give a different notification id for every notification that you create.
Hopefully it will work

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. The idea was to close the application and start over again. that way the resources will be freed and it'll be possible that way. When I force close the app it's working fine.